# Auto generation of meta description in magento

Tags: magento

I want auto generation of meta description in magento CE for my products liks this:
Buy {product name} for Rs {price} at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for {publihser}

Comment: Try and share some of the code you have so far, otherwise you're basically asking us to code something for you...

Answer (score 0):

From above description, I am assuming that you want to set meta description dynamically for products.

Please use below code in your controller's action:

```
$productName = $_product->getName();

$price = {your custom price};
$publisher = {Publisher name};
$description = 'Buy '.$productName.' for Rs '.$price.' at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for '.$publisher;

$root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root');
$template = "page/3columns.phtml";
$root->setTemplate($template);

$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
$head->setTitle("Your Title");
$head->setKeywords("your, keywords, anything");
$head->setDescription($description);
```

I hope, it will help.. :)